# How does my Internet Service Provider knows the location of the VPN server if the data has just been encrypted by the VPN software?

Tags: tcp, ip, vpn

A **VPN software** encrypts data before sending to the **Internet System Provider**, so he can send to the data to the **VPN Server.**
How does the **ISP** knows the location of the **VPN server** if the data has just been encrypted??
This question came to my head after reading this steps:

When the connection has been established, the following will happen to your data:

1. The VPN software on your computer encrypts your data traffic and sends it to the VPN server through a secure connection. The data also goes through your Internet Service Provider, but they can no longer snoop because of the encryption.
2. The encrypted data from your computer is decrypted by the VPN server.
3. The VPN server will send your data on to the internet and receive a reply, which is meant for you, the user.
4. The traffic is then encrypted again by the VPN-server and is sent back to you.
5. The VPN-software on your device will decrypt the data so you can actually understand and use it.

Comment: postal offices deliver mails despite content being sealed. they use contact data written at envelope. the same is with data frames which are sent to VPN provider - ISP knows addressee and know the fact that some message was sent but they do not know what is inside. VPN connection just wraps envelope of one mail into another so ISP sees outer envelope (which displays that you send "mail" to VPN provider) but do not see internal envelope because it is encrypted. when VPN provider gets your mail it opens envelope and gets extra mail out of envelope and sends that mail further.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks for your answer